# Should Apache Kafka and Hadoop be installed seperatedly (on a diffrent cluster)?

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka

Should Apache Kafka and Hadoop be installed  seperatedly (on a diffrent cluster) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kafka is a distributed publish-subscribe messaging system that is designed to be fast, scalable, and durable. You can go for Kafka if the data will be consumed by 
multiple applications.

Hope this link helps.. it has some info in it
http://www.datanami.com/2014/12/02/kafka-run-natively-hadoop/